# 画像を置くディレクトリについて

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, swift2

画像をたくさん使うアプリを開発する場合に、どのように画像を置けばいいのかという質問です
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この画像のように「img1.png」「img2.png」で済めばいいですが、画像が多くなればそれだけ煩雑になると思います
日曜プログラミング程度ではこれでいいかもしれませんが、実際ストアに公開されているアプリはどのように管理しているのでしょうか？

自分はAssets.xcassetsをうまく使うか、画像用のディレクトリを用意しているのかというふうに考えています
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

個人的には`Assets.xcassets`を使う方が良いと思います。

理由は、下記2点です。

**1. 端末の画面サイズや解像度に合わせて、最適な画像を適用してくれる**
**2. GoogleのMaterial iconsが適用しやすい**

続いて、各理由の詳細について説明します。

【1．端末の画面サイズや解像度に合わせて、最適な画像を適用してくれる】
iOSアプリでは、(Android端末ほどではないのものの)画面サイズの種類が増えてきました。
1つの画像を追加しても全ての端末に対して最適な解像度ではないと思います。

【2．GoogleのMaterial iconsが適用しやすい】
私は[GoogleのMaterial icons](https://design.google.com/icons/)を利用することがあるのですが、
アイコンをDLしてみるとiOS用のアイコンが`Assets.xcassets`で設定する前提で取得できます。
Googleも利用している形ですので、納得感もあるかと。

以上、少しでも参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: 1については納得です。２についてですが、リンクを見たところpngとsvg形式でダウンロード可能でした。svg形式の画像をそのままassetsに入れていいということですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。確かにSVG形式もあるのですが、そのままAssets Catalogに使うことが実はできません。PDF形式に変換が必要なようで、その際の画像サイズには注意が必要です。また、Xcodeでビルド時に結局、PNGファイルを出力しているという話もあるので、SVGの利用とPNGの利用でどちらが楽ということもなさそうです。(SVGを使うことで、見かけ上のファイル数は減りますね。)こちらに詳しく書いてありましたので、参考にしてみてください。http://qiita.com/Yuta/items/ad02e5e93694c8add089

Comment: PDFに変換したのちにassetsに入れて使えばいいですね！参考になりました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

私は仕事で複数の会社のプロジェクトを見ていますが、全部１つのAsset Catalog（`Assets.xcassets`）に入れるのが一般的ですね。

Asset Catalogの中でサブフォルダに分けることもできるので、画像が増えてきたら、適宜、内部にフォルダを作って整理します。その分け方はプロジェクトによってまちまちですね。
（Common、Button、Menu、みたいなところもありますし、画面ごとのところもあります。）